# Does this tag [reflect] any purpose?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [reflect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflect) doesn't have a tag wiki but it there [are a few questions tagged with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflect).

Some of these questions seem to be about [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflection) and that tag already exists.

Should this tag be synonymized/merged with [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflection), burninated, a wiki added that [reflect]s the real purpose of the tag or should something else happen with it?

Comment: Can't really speak for other tags, but at least for the [16 java  questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breflect%5D+is%3Aq+%5Bjava%5D) they should probably be retagged to `[reflection]`. There are also [61 Go questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breflect%5D+is%3Aq+%5Bgo%5D) which talk about the [reflect package](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/). They could also be tagged with `[reflection]`.  Some `[angular]` questions talk about some `reflect`-module, but for that we'd need a SME

Comment: `[reflect]` has been synonymized to `[reflection]`. Was that the intended outcome?

Answer (score 13):

This tag is ambiguous and thus should be disambiguated (replaced with more specific tags in all questions, after which it'll be automatically deleted after a day):

- [reflect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflect) + [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) --> <s>[java-reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-reflection)</s> [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) + [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflection) as per [Retag [java-reflection] to [java] + [reflection]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409100/retag-java-reflection-to-java-reflection)
- [reflect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflect) + [go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go) --> [go-reflect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-reflect)
- [reflect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflect) + [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) --> A tag about the [built-in `Reflect` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect). There doesn't seem to be an existing one, so I propose [javascript-reflect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-reflect)

Comment: The tag `[java-reflection]` should probably be retagged to `[java] + [reflection]` and then removed. But that is another story

Comment: @Lino you mean remove [reflection]?

Comment: Now the question arises again. Do we need `[go-reflect]`? Or is `[go]`+`[reflection]` the better target? (The same of course for the proposed `[javascript-reflect]` tag)

Comment: Is "reflect" even a thing? If you know what "reflect" is, please link to some hint

Comment: @DanielW. there are a bunch of references in both question and answer to various things called "reflect". So not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: Reflect/ion isn't even the same in the 3 tags involved. One is even a object about interceptable operations, it isn't even a concept. We don't need a tag that means 3 different things.

Comment: @Lino As the question post says, [tag:go-reflect] is about a Go package called "reflect", not about reflection in Go in general.