# Retag [java-reflection] to [java] + [reflection]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

[Today I noticed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/409099/5515060) the [java-reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-reflection) tag.

It seems to me that it could simply be retagged to [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)[reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflection) which was used together 7,061 times. In contrast the [java-reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-reflection) is only used 48 times.

Out of the total 48 questions:

- [20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-reflection+java+reflection) are tagged with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflection) -> simply remove [java-reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-reflection)
- [22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-reflection+java+-reflection) are tagged with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) but not [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflection) -> replace [java-reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-reflection) with [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflection)
- [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-reflection+-java) are not tagged  with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) -> should be looked at individually

As the tag is only sparsely used I don't think that it needs to be synonymized.

Comment: The tag cleanup of [reflect] can probably be done together with [java-reflection]

Comment: This post was created to poll the community's response to whether this specific retag should be completed, [in the midst of other cleanup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409092/does-this-tag-reflect-any-purpose#comment854282_409099) for [reflect]. The cleanup question itself is very closely related, but not the same IMO, and shouldn't be closed as a dupe.

Comment: Support, by analogy with https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393153/status-of-removing-the-excel-vba-and-similar-vba-tags

Comment: I disagree with the closure of this post. I agree that the duplicate and this question are related. (which is why I created this question in the first place). But the duplicate is talking about `[reflect]` and what should be done with it (i.e. burnination). While this one is explicitly talking about a simple retag request. But if I'm mistaken, please let me know

Comment: I agree with your proposal, but the community has always seemed to favor the *more specific* tags to combinations of tags.  When I ask why, I'm told that it's because you can *follow* the more specific tag.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I feel the same, and I think that creating tags like `java-reflection` instead of using `java` and `reflection` is not the way how tags should work. But that's how it is desired on SO and probably not a subject for discussion.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the retag I've linked to showcases the opposite

Comment: Since there are over 7,000 questions tagged `java` + `reflection`, but only dozens of questions tagged `java-reflection`, following the latter tag wouldn't be useful for seeing these questions anyway. The 20 + 22 + 6 questions are now all retagged.

Comment: @RobertHarvey `reflection` is a general topic. We also don't have a `java-arrays` tag, just so people can follow them more easily. That's why we have filters.

Comment: @RobertHarvey try to follow only reflection and java. You can't. You are shown questions with both reflection or java. There's no "and" for tag follow. They are right. If you find that following specific tag isn't useful, then maybe neither tag should exist.

Comment: @Braiam Maybe not follow, but filter and search certainly have an `and` option.

Comment: @MegaIng yet, we take the number of follows to see if the tag is useful or not. BTW, while either would be functionally the same for search, having them separated makes at least one use case significantly worse.

Comment: @Braiam so in your logic we should replace `[java][integer]` with `[java-integer]`? Because `[integer]` only got ~800 followers?

Comment: No, just keep java without integer. We don't need either the combination of both tags or a single tag, do we?

Comment: @Braiam so just remove all tags? Because the information is already present in each question?

Comment: No, just remove those that aren't useful. Java is useful. Integer is not useful.

Comment: Does this proposal also hold for `[go-reflect]` being retagged to `[go] + [reflection]`? If not then why is Java different to Go? Similar question for any other languages with reflection such as `[andriod-reflection]`, `[scala-reflect]` or `[kotlin-reflect]`?

Comment: @MT0 that could be argued. It seems that `[lang][reflection]` is more commonly used, than `[lang-reflect(ion)]`. Kotlin: [328](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin+reflection) vs [90](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kotlin-reflect), Scala: [978](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala+reflection) vs [235](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala-reflect), Android: [656](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+reflection) vs [10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-reflection). 1/2

Comment: @MT0 2/2 Go: [583](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go+reflection) vs [84](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-reflect), other tag that heavily use `[lang][reflection]` are `[c#]` and `[python]` with [10,494](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+reflection), resp. [238](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+reflection) questions each

Comment: @Braiam: If you look for questions to answer by using a custom search filter, that search can include `([java] & [reflection])` I think.  Or just filter out other languages you don't want to see via tag ignore stuff.

Comment: @PeterCordes search != follow. Followers>search. We use followers as a proxy of how useful a tag really is. Search is for Google, SE doesn't care about searching using internal tools.

Comment: @Braiam: IDK about you, but I find new questions to answer by using a custom search filter like `[assembly] or [x86*] or [sse*]` etc, sort by "active".  This works better for me than tag "follow" did, years ago when I was starting to use SO, and I've stuck with doing it this way.  Do people actually still bother to follow tags?   Also, I don't see what google has to do with SE's internal search either.

Comment: @MT0 [tag:go-reflect] is about a Go package called "Reflect". So no.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It seems that someone cleanup the [java-reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-reflection) tag.